# Regarding the proxy service with AMQP transport

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

This is regarding proxy service with RabbitMQ AMQP transport where I am stuck. Below is the use case.

I am using the WSO2 ESB to process the set of files (XML or CSV). I have written a proxy service from there I am calling a sequence which is common set of instructions to execute for similar files with different data sets.In this sequence have used Iterator mediator for processing each file sequentially.and I am splitting the files and publishing the the transformed(to JSON) msgs to a consumer queue using RabbitMQ msg broker. Parallel to this i have written a consumer proxy with AMQP transports which will be waiting for the response from back end.

Now my question is that control should back to the iterator to process the next file? I am stuck here. If anyone has resolved the similar problem please your help will be appreciated.

Use case :

1. Process the files sequentially (ex:4 files) which are placed in one folder.
2. pick one file at a time and split the file and send each batch as a message to RabbitMQ. From RabitMQ the messages will be consumed by back end.
3. The response received by a ReplyTo queue.
4. Again the step 2 should be performed for the next file.

The design which i have considered is as below:

1. First a proxy service( specific to a set of files) will be called.
2. From the proxy the main sequence will be called.
3. The main sequence consists of an Iterator(For each file). In the Iterator have written a custom class mediator which will read the file and split the file and then call one more sequence(which has logic for transformation) and then send the batch as a message to back end consumer.
   4.I have written a consumer proxy as below which will be up and listening to replyTo queue.

Now my question is , From this consumer proxy how I can make the control to go back to the main sequence Iterator so that it will pick the next file and process.

Proxy i have created exactly as is in the documentation of WSO2
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport

Comment: can you share the xml proxy config?

Comment: Your usecase is not clear, what do you mean by "Parallel to this i have written a consumer proxy with AMQP transports which will be waiting for the response from back end." ?

Comment: @JorgeInfanteOsorio  and ycr I am elaborating it more by editing the post